# How to search/filtering data with viewmodels & enum select list in ASP.NET Core using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, checkbox

I have an enum `Grade` in my `EnrollmentVM` class (view models)

```
[Flags]
public enum Grade
{
    [Display(Name = "A")]
    A = 1,
    [Display(Name = "B")]
    B = 2,
    [Display(Name = "C")]
    C = 3,
    [Display(Name = "D")]
    D = 4,
    [Display(Name = "F")]
    F = 5,
}

public class EnrollmentVM : IValidatableObject
{
    public List<Enrollment> EnrollmentList { get; set; }     
        
    [Display(Name = "Grade :")] // attribute
    public Grade? Grade { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my controller for filtering

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexProses(Grade? currentFilter, int? pageNumber)
{
    if (model.Grade != null)
    {
        pageNumber = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        model.Grade = currentFilter;
    }

    var enroll = from s in _context.Enrollments
                                   .Include(e => e.Course)
                                   .Include(e => e.Student) 
                 select s;  

    if (model.Grade != null)
    {
        enroll = enroll.Where(s => s.Grade == model.Grade);
    }
}
```

But then I get an error on this line

```
enroll = enroll.Where(s => s.Grade == model.Grade);
```

Any idea how to search grade list with checkbox? Because before this I use select dropdown for my search, here's the view for select dropdown search

```
<label asp-for="Grade"></label>
<select asp-for="Grade" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Grade>()">
    <option selected="selected">@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]</option>
</select>
```

and I'm confused on how the write the input checkbox, is it using looping like for/foreach or not. Thank you!

Comment: @marc_s it says operator == cannot be applied

Comment: Since the `Grade` field in your model is nullable - you'll need to use `s => s.Grade == model.Grade.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

Why `operator == cannot be applied` ：you could check if the type of model.Grade is same with the type of model.Grade

How to search grade list with checkbox:

You could create five checkbox with the same name attr with the parameter in your controller(in your case it was currentFilter)

And I tried as below:

```
<form asp-action="Filter" method="post">
        <a>GradeA</a>
        <input type="checkbox" name="currentFilter" value="A" />
        <a>GradeB</a>
        <input type="checkbox" name="currentFilter" value="B" />
        <a>GradeC</a>
        <input type="checkbox" name="currentFilter" value="C" />
        <a>GradeD</a>
        <input type="checkbox" name="currentFilter" value="D" />
        <a>GradeE</a>
        <input type="checkbox" name="currentFilter" value="E" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("input[name='currentFilter']").click(function () {
            $("input[name='currentFilter']").prop("checked", false)
            $(this).prop("checked", "checked")
        });
    </script>
```

Result:

[image]

You could also try with `<input type="radio".....>`